# Many to many relationship in SQL server - To add reference in foreign table when insertion does not happen in base table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables `User` and `Item`. The user table will have user details and item table will have unique entries of the item.

Now I am creating a many to many relationship where there is a separate table called `List` which references the primary keys of both the table as foreign key. Now each user will pass a csv string which will contain all the items he wants. These items will be added  to the item table and its Id along with user Id will be placed in list table.

The tables are created like this....

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
Item_Id int identity(1,1) not null,
Item_Name varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Item_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.List
(
Item_Id int not null,
Users_Id varchar(11) not null,
);
```

The stored procedure looks something like this...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Entry] 
    @User_Id varchar(11)
    @Items VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
as 
begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.Item
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Item_Id INTO @OutputTbl(Item_Id) 
       SELECT Item_Name
       FROM [dbo].[Split] ( @Items, ',')  -- call the split function 

    INSERT INTO dbo.List
       SELECT Item_Id, @User_Id 
       FROM @OutputTbl
end
GO
```

Now when there is a duplicate of the `Item` name, I want to skip the insertion in `Item` table but the entry alone should be placed in the `List` table.

For example if User1 has given list "Soap,Shampoo" and it is inserted with ids 1 , 2 and the refrences will be added in List table.
Now when User2 makes the list "Brush,Soap" the name Soap should not be duplicated in Item table but the Id of the soap should be added in the reference table like

```
    UserID    |   ItemID
  ---------------------------
    User1         1 
    User1         2 
    User2         3 
    User2         1
```

This seems hard for me because I retrieve the Id of the inserted records and place them in list table. How to place them in List table when the name is already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my code to actually store the names as temptable instead of Ids and then I used Inner join to insert the Id in List from the corresponding names in the temptable.The stored procedure that works for me is...

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Entry]
@Users_Id varchar(11),
@Items VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
as 
begin
DECLARE @ItemNames TABLE (Item_Names VARCHAR(150));

INSERT INTO @ItemNames 
SELECT Item_Name  
FROM [dbo].[Split] ( @Items, ',')  -- call the split function 

INSERT INTO dbo.Item
SELECT Item_Names
FROM @ItemNames list
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Item i WHERE i.Item_Name = list.Item_Names);

INSERT INTO dbo.List(Item_Id,Users_Id)
SELECT  Item_Id,@Users_Id 
FROM @ItemNames list
INNER JOIN dbo.Item 
    ON list.Item_Names = dbo.Item.Item_Name;
end
GO
```

Comment: Thanks its help for me 1+

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Entry] 
    @User_Id varchar(11)
    @Items VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
as 
begin
    DECLARE @Items TABLE (Name VARCHAR(150));

    -- call the split function 
    INSERT INTO @ItemNames
       SELECT Item_Name
       FROM [dbo].[Split] ( @Items, ',');

    -- insert all new items into items
    INSERT INTO dbo.Item
    SELECT Item_Name
       FROM @Items
    except 
    select item_name from dbo.Item;

    -- insert user/item into list
    INSERT INTO dbo.List
    SELECT distinct Item_Id, @User_Id 
    from @Items iu
    join dbo.Item i on iu.item_name=i.item_name;
end
GO
```

this way you only insert names which aren't in the table yet and have to join the the whole list of items and insert into the mapping table

Comment: I have edited my question to ask what I really wanted to do?? How do i insert the Id of the keyword into List if it is already present in the Item, since Id of those which are inserted only will be returned by my procedure and those alone will be inserted in List table

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be trying to do too much at once. The `PROC` appears to have the following 3 concerns:

1. Splitting out the list of Items Names from the @Items input comma delimited string
2. Maintaining the `dbo.Item` table with a unique set of all 'seen' item names (i.e. adding new items to the table)
3. Maintaining `dbo.List` with the `User : ItemId` mappings irrespective of whether the item is 'new' or 'existing'.

I would break up the concerns accordingly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Entry] 
    @User_Id varchar(11),
    @Items VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ItemNames TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(50));
    DECLARE @ItemIds TABLE (Item_Id INT);

    INSERT INTO @ItemNames(Name)
        SELECT Item_Name FROM [dbo].[Split] ( @Items, ',');

    INSERT INTO dbo.Item(Item_Id)
        SELECT Name
        FROM @ItemNames new
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Item i WHERE i.Item_Id = new.Name);

    INSERT INTO dbo.List(itm.Item_Id, User_Id)
       SELECT Item_Id, @User_Id 
       FROM @ItemNames new
        INNER JOIN dbo.Item itm
        ON itm.Item_Id = new.Name;
END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00122/1)